Grafted into what?
Just taking a step back; grafting is a horticultural process by which you join TWO or more plants so that the tissue can grow together. Saul in Romans 11:17, 19, 23 and 23 talks about the Gentile Romans of Italy being able to be graffed into the family of Yisra'el.
How is it misinterpreted to suggest that the Gentile nations which comprise "the church" have replaced the blinded portion of Israel from Isaiah 6:8 and the remnant who are awake to this day as recorded in Romans 11:5;25?
Romans 11:5 Even so then at this present time also there is a remnant according to the election of grace.
KJV Romans 11:25 "For I would not, brethren, that ye should be ignorant of this mystery, lest ye should be wise in your own conceits; that blindness in part is happened to Israel, until the fulness of the Gentiles be come in."

Who said anything about "replacement" - Christians are grafted into a "tree" of spiritual Israel.

the title might benefit from graffing > grafting to help others interested in the same topic/keyword to find it. I regret I can't shed light on the question, but often with grafting one plant's fruit is nurtured by the other's roots - and hopefully someone has studied the history of what was done

If this is about "replacement theology" it might be better to ask on the Christianity site as they deal more with theology. If I'm mistaken please clarify your question.

Grafted in to have access to the "root and fatness" of the tree...not grafted into the covenant promises of Israel.

“Remnant” are all those thousands of Jews who accepted Christ as the promised Messiah by the preaching of the apostles, whom Paul well knew when he wrote his letter to Romans and whom Paul identified also himself with.
A bush metaphor shows that: some branches of the bush fell, on their empty platform wild olive twigs (believing pagans) were engrafted, but some branches did not fall, so what is the problem? As in horticulture, so in life.

It is a good explanation of the metaphor.  The branches that did not fall (stumble) indeed represent Peter and believing Israel, while the fallen branches (unbelieving Jews) may join believing Gentiles through Paul. It is why Paul is able to say that there is currently "no difference", as they have fallen from their elevated status with God and are now equal with us Gentile "dogs". So, only by God's grace through our faith may any of the fallen Jews or outsiders be "grafted" in. Your simple explanation makes it easy to see how and why there is a difference between Peter and Paul (Gal 2:7-9).+1

@MarkVestal Thanks!

Serious MetaphorRomans 11 written by the Apostle Paul illustrates an important and sober reality: Jesus is the way, the truth, and the life. There is no other salvation nor eternal life other than what is found in Jesus (Jeshua, Messiah, the Anointed One, the Savior of the world).
As every arborist knows, even a healthy tree will have defective branches, dead branches, which need to be pruned away. This makes room for new branches to grow, and for new branches to be grafted in to fill the empty spaces so no fruitfulness is lost.
In like MannerIn the same way, the redemptive plan of God through the ages, using the Jewish nation as a vehicle to bring us to the ultimate Savior, Jesus Christ, is presented by Paul with the simile of a tree of life. And those of the Israeli race who accepted Jesus as Messiah are pictured as still being part of that redemptive tree, enjoying the life giving sap of joyous salvation! They are enjoying the fruit that was intended by God to become mature at the arrival of Jesus.
Unfortunately, when Jesus came unto His own, His own received Him not (John 1). These are they whom Paul pictured as branches being broken off!  This judgment is no different than what happened to Israelis in the Tanakh who turned their backs on God. Rebellion and unfaithfulness has dire consequences all throughout history.
Gentile ReceptivenessAs was intended in the promise God made to Abraham, the whole world was to be blessed in his Seed which is Christ (See Galatians). So in like manner, Paul pictured these believing Gentiles who have accepted Jesus, as branches grafted in! Gentiles are part of God's redemptive plan, and enjoy the sap of life for a joyous salvation experience!
Grafted Back InPaul made it clear, however, that it was still possible for Israelis to be part of the tree of salvation,if they repented and became disciples of Jesus, too. There is still room on the tree for their branches...and there will always be room. The decision is theirs, just as Gentiles must decide to become disciples. "Equal opportunity" BUT, equal judgment, if they don't respond to the call of God.
In a sense there is no replacement since there is plenty of room on this tree for all nations! But there is evidence of small stubs where once grew limbs.
